# How to set combo-box as default

Tags: combobox, progress-4gl

How to clear a combo-box selected values when clicking on a 'Clear' button? When the time of clicking clear button, it needs to set it as default. 
I wrote it as;

```
DO:
    ASSIGN
    coCombo-2:SCREEN-VALUE IN FRAME {&FRAME-NAME} = "".
    coCombo-3:SCREEN-VALUE IN FRAME {&FRAME-NAME} = "".
END.
```

"But this is not working."

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign a space instead of an empty string

```
DO:
    ASSIGN
    coCombo-2:SCREEN-VALUE IN FRAME {&FRAME-NAME} = " ".
    coCombo-3:SCREEN-VALUE IN FRAME {&FRAME-NAME} = " ".
END.
```

see also https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P21248